# Yii2 ActiveRecord with relation result convert to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2, foreign-keys

I have a database table called textAreas with a Yii2 ActiveRecord model with a primary key `id` column (and some other columns, but they don't matter).

I also have a table called text with a Yii2 ActiveRecord model, which is called TextCtrl, with a primary key `id`, foreign key `textControllerId` which is linked to `id` from textAreas, a column called `lang` and a column called `content`. One textArea has many texts (which is basically the same text in different languages).

Now the user is able to select a language. Then I would like to select all textAreas out of the table and provide them with the correct content, based on the `lang` selection of the user.

Normally this is done by a SQL join, but I thought the ActiveRecord should also provide this functionality.

My code so far:
textAreas.php:

```
//TextAreas.php ActiveRecord model for table textAreas

class TextAreas extends ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @property int $id
     * @property int $width
     * @property int $height
     */

    /**
     * @ignore
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return "{{textAreas}}";
    }

    /**
     * Get all textAreas and their dimensions if user is authorized and website in development mode
     */
    public static function getAllTextAreas()
    {
        // check if user is authorized and website is in development mode
        if(! Yii::$app->user->can('updateContent') || YII_ENV != 'dev')
        {
            $textArea = 'notAuthorized';
            return [$textArea];
        }

        // get all textareas and their properties
        $textArea = self::find()
            ->joinWith('text')
            ->all();

        return $textArea;
    }

    /**
     * fill textareas with content
     * @param int $lang language setting, if null language from session is used
     */
    public function getText($lang = null)
    {
        //get language from session
        if(!$lang)
        {
            $lang = LangCtrl::getStoredLanguage();
        }

        //return the content
        return $this->hasOne(TextCtrl::className(), ['textControllerId' => 'id'])
                ->where(['lang' => $lang]);
    }
}
```

textCtrl.php ActiveRecord model for text table:

```
//TextCtrl ActiveRecord model for text table

class TextCtrl extends ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @property int $id
     * @property int $textControllerId id of text block on web page
     * @property int $lang language of text
     * @property string $content the text itself
     */

    /**
     * @ignore
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return "{{text}}";  
    }

    //Other methods which don't matter
}
```

Now, in a controller action I'm doing this:

```
$textAreas = TextAreas::getAllTextAreas();

$response = Yii::$app->response;
$response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;  

return $textAreas;
```

Which gives the result:

```
[{"id":1,"width":100,"height":16},{"id":2,"width":100,"height":16}, more database entries...]
```

But I actually wanted something like

```
[{"id":1,"width":100,"height":16,"content":"MyContent1"},{"id":2,"width":100,"height":16,"content":"MyContent2"}, more database entries...]
```

Where the `content` fields are filled with the contents from the `text` table.

Is somebody able to provide some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Converting Objects to Arrays](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-array#converting-objects-to-arrays):

```
$textAreas = TextAreas::getAllTextAreas();

$response = Yii::$app->response;
$response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON; 

return ArrayHelper::toArray($textAreas, [
    TextAreas::class => [
        'id',
        'width',
        'height',
        'content' => function ($data) {
            return $data->text->text;
        },
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can add new field in fields() method, based on your relation:

```
public function fields()
{
    return array_merge(
        parent::fields(),
        [
            'content' => function () {
                if (!$this->text) {
                    return '';
                }

                return $this->text->content;
            },
        ]
    );
}
```